# C# searching through lists

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code I'm using 3 foreach statements.  I'm just looking to populate a list when a list of items matches another but the ones that don't match also have to be added.  So I was wondering if there is an easier way to do the following.

```
        List<T> ds = new List<T>();  //is populated           
        foreach (var b in template.Bs)
        {
            List<BD> tempList = new List<BD>();
            foreach (BD bd in b.BDs)
            {
                Boolean found = false;
                foreach (DV dv in items)
                {
                    if (bd.C == dv.C)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        tempList.Add(new BD ()
                        {
                            //populating
                        });
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                    tempList.Add(new BD()
                    {
                        //populating
                    });
            }

        }
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual code you want help with... this fragment populates 'tempList' which is local to the outer foreach loop, so effectively, the outer loop does not really achieve anything!?

Comment: The outer loop goes through the different groups of lists.  The next loop loops through that list.  The next loop, loops through a list that is trying to match and pass data to the new list created but it still needs to maintain the 2 foreach list.  so documents that don't match plus ones that do match with the inner foreach loop.  See where this gets complicated?

Comment: What makes it complicated is that your code does not reflect what you are saying... if you want help *improving* your algorithm, make sure it works first... for example 'the next loop loops through that list', no it doesn't... it uses this variable(?) called 'binder' that you do not declare anywhere...

Comment: sorry, was trying to make it generic and don't want to include all the code that is outside/inside those loops because it would get messy.  So was just trying to make it generic.  I updated it.

Comment: I have tried to use LINQ and I initially did when I just had to get the documents that matched but didn't work for getting items inside and outside that list.

Comment: Its very difficult to read and understand what you are trying to achieve here. Class/variable names are meaningless and then i don't see "items" being declared anywhere.
I am sure there can be a solution using linq here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relationship between `ds` and `tempList` is not clear, but it looks to me like your inner loops are really a left outer join:

```
List<T> ds = new List<T>();  //is populated           
foreach (var b in template.Bs)
{
    var newBDs = from bd in b.BDs
                 join dv in items on bd.C equals dv.C into j
                 from dv in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select dv == null ? NoMatch(bd) : Match(bd, dv);

    List<BD> tempList = newBDs.ToList();

    // Do something with tempList
}
```

For each `b` in `template.Bs`, we're matching `bd`'s from `b.BDs` with `dv`'s in `items`. We then use `DefaultIfEmpty()` to put `null` in `dv` if there was no match, which we then use to determine which projection method to call: `NoMatch()` would create a new `BD` based on the unmatched `bd`, and `Match()` would create a new `BD` based on the matched `bd` and `dv`.

That whole query is represented by `newBDs`, which will be `IEnumerable<BD>`. We can then buffer that sequence into `tempList` or do something else useful with it.

Comment: I implemented that and it works perfect!  Thanks again, so much!